# How to write decimal type to redshift using awsglue?

Tags: pyspark, null, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a variety of columns to redshift from a dynamic frame using the [DynamicFrameWriter.from_jdbc_conf](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-writer.html) method, but all DECIMAL fields end up as a column of NULLs.

The ETL pulls in from some redshift views, and eventually writes back to a redshift table using the aforementioned method. In general this works for other datatypes, but adding a statement as simple as `SELECT CAST(12.34 AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS decimal_test` results in a column full of NULLs. In pyspark, I can print out the column and see the decimal values immediately before they are written as NULLs to the redshift table. When I look at the schema on redshift, I can see the column decimal_test has a type of NUMERIC(4, 2). What could be causing this failure?

Comment: What is the datatype of the target field in redshift?

Comment: in this example it is NUMERIC(4, 2)

Comment: Could you add your ETL code here?